# How do I Disable Android Device Manager on Sold Device?

Tags: android-device-manager

I am a GSuite user and a ZTE Axon 7 device that I recently sold via SWAPPA was setup with Android Device Manager. I did a factory reset on the device, but when the buyer powered on the device, he said that the device indicated that it was already associated with a Google account and he would need the credentials to configure it. I went into the standard Find my Device and tried to remove it, and it appeared to have been removed from whatever screen I was on, but the buyer is still complaining. I am still seeing the device here: https://www.google.com/android/find I wondered if GSuite's device management might be at play, and just went there to "delete" it. Am wondering what else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

An answer that works... Give him your email and password to unlock the device. Once they are in and working, change your password.

Yes, it has potential risks, but 99.99% of the time this would work out just fine.